# How can I preview the androidx.recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

I don't know to add a Recycler View in android x.
It only shows me:

[image: https://ibb.co/W08gzdZ]

Comment: maybe you have added and its something to do with preview?

Comment: The gray rectangle and class name usually appear when Android Studio can't find (or can't compile) the referenced class. It's likely that you need to add a gradle dependency on the correct androidx library.

Answer (score 1):

clean and rebuild project will solve

Answer (score 0):

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and for the java part

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
recyclerView.setAdapter(YOUR_ADAPTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`xmlns:tools`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) attribute in your root element and then just add `tools:listitem` to your `RecyclerView`.

```
<RootTag
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            ...
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/my_list_item" />

</RootTag>
```